# Codeigniter file path is not stored properly in database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, stored-procedures, file-upload

The file path of the file I'm trying to upload is not stored properly.

My only problem now is, instead of storing this path:

> C:/xampp/htdocs/dev/csbrms/upload/file.xlsx

it only stores:

> C:/xampp/htdocs/dev/csbrms/upl

this is my code

view.php

```
<input type = "file" name = "userfile" id="userfile"/>
```

controller.php

```
$upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
$file_name =   $upload_data['file_name'];


$data = array(...
'file_path'       => $file_name,
);
```

model.php

```
function add_records($data){

    try {

    $sql = "CALL `sp_add_user_request`(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            $result = $this->csbrms->query($sql,$data); // $data included 3 param and binding & query to db
            $this->csbrms->close();


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
        }
```

Comment: Could you check your database field size? It might be limited to certain number of characters.

Comment: check field size in database.

Comment: The maximum length for it was 200.

Comment: Check File Size !

Answer (score 1):

You are using file_path to store your file info, whereas you probably want to use full_path which will include the path and filename.

```
$file =   $upload_data['full_path'];
```

You can see all the return fields for the helper function in the docs here:
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::data

But here is the example return array with the fields you can use:

```
Array
(
    [file_name]     => mypic.jpg
    [file_type]     => image/jpeg
    [file_path]     => /path/to/your/upload/
    [full_path]     => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
    [raw_name]      => mypic
    [orig_name]     => mypic.jpg
    [client_name]   => mypic.jpg
    [file_ext]      => .jpg
    [file_size]     => 22.2
    [is_image]      => 1
    [image_width]   => 800
    [image_height]  => 600
    [image_type]    => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

Hope that helps,

Paul.

Comment: hi, thanks for this. I've tried it already, and still the path that was stored was still incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Check your field size in database. The path is being truncated due to the size of the column/field in the table where the path is being stored.